# HIbernate one to many / Many to one using @Embeddable Annotation

Tags: java, hibernate

When I'm trying to save the Customer Object the exception states that it cannot insert NULL into ()...

I believe the exception is caused due to the @Embeddable Annotation used

But when I am explicit setting the value of customer_id it works fine but the value is not saved as foreign key in Customerphone table.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "CUSTOMER")
public class Customer implements java.io.Serializable {

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "Customer")
    public Set<CustomerPhone> getCustomerPhones() {
        return this.CustomerPhones;
    }
}
```

---

```
@Entity
@Table(name="CUSTOMER_PHONE")
public class CustomerPhone  implements java.io.Serializable {

    private CustomerPhoneId id;

    @EmbeddedId
    @AttributeOverrides( {
        @AttributeOverride(name="customerId", column=@Column(name="CUSTOMER_ID", nullable=false, precision=22, scale=0) ), 
        @AttributeOverride(name="phoneTypeCd", column=@Column(name="PHONE_TYPE_CD", nullable=false, length=5) ) } )
    public CustomerPhoneId getId() {
        return this.id;
    }

    public void setId(CustomerPhoneId id) {
        this.id = id;
    }


    @ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name="CUSTOMER_ID", nullable=false, insertable=false, updatable=false)
    public Customer getCustomer() {
        return this.stpCustomer;
    }

}
```

---

```
@Embeddable
public class CustomerPhoneId  implements java.io.Serializable {

    private BigDecimal customerId;

    @Column(name="CUSTOMER_ID", nullable=false, precision=22, scale=0)
    public BigDecimal getCustomerId() {
        return this.customerId;
    }

}
```

Comment: ad complete Customer class

Answer (score 0):

Your ID does not have a Generation schema, like `@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)`.

In these cases, you need to set an ID manually, in your case, you need to set `customerId` manually before persisting.